# How to move down a object using button in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-image

Actually I want to do something like that (Image attached):

[image]

There have a box, and two buttons. If I press `button 1` then the `box` moved left. And if I press `button 2` then the `box` moved right.

I want, when the `box` move right and overcome the `bar 1` then the `box` moved down on the `bar 2`.
But I have no idea how to do it.

**Here is my code:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Animated,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      left: 20,
    };
  }

  moveRight = () => {
    this.setState({left: this.state.left + 10}); // 10 is value of change.
  };

  moveLeft = () => {
    this.setState({left: this.state.left - 10}); // 10 is value of change.
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          style={{left: this.state.left, height: 120, width: 120}}
          source={require('./assets/box.png')}
        />

        <Image
          style={{height: 20, width: 180, marginTop: -12, marginLeft: 25}}
          source={require('./assets/log.png')}
        />

        <Image
          style={{height: 20, width: 200, marginTop: 150, marginLeft: 185}}
          source={require('./assets/log.png')}
        />

        <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.moveLeft}>
            <Image
              style={{height: 60, width: 60}}
              source={require('./assets/left-button.png')}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.moveRight}>
            <Image
              style={{height: 60, width: 60}}
              source={require('./assets/right-button.png')}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  textCenter: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  levelHeading: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 35,
    color: '#CC8A4F',
  },
  buttonsContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginTop: 200,
    paddingLeft: 80,
    paddingRight: 80,
  },
});
```

**Please help me!**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Animated, Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  const moveAnimation = new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 10, y: 450 });
  useEffect(() => {
    moveAnimation;
  }, []);

  const _moveBallLeft = () => {
    Animated.spring(moveAnimation, {
      toValue: { x: 250, y: 450 },
    }).start();
  };
  const _moveBallRight = () => {
    Animated.spring(moveAnimation, {
      toValue: { x: 10, y: 450 },
    }).start();
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Animated.View style={[styles.tennisBall, moveAnimation.getLayout()]}>
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>ball</Text>
        </View>
      </Animated.View>

      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: "row-reverse",
          justifyContent: "space-evenly",
        }}
      >
        <View style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}>
          <Button title=">" onPress={_moveBallLeft}></Button>
        </View>
        <View style={{ alignSelf: "center", marginLeft: "2%" }}>
          <Button title="<" onPress={_moveBallRight}></Button>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
export default App;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 2,
    backgroundColor: "#ecf0f1",
  },
  tennisBall: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "greenyellow",
    borderRadius: 100,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
  },
  button: {
    paddingTop: 24,
    paddingBottom: 24,
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 24,
    color: "#333",
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I sending the solution of the program that your provided image. your can change X and Y axis values then you can move direction of the box easily. you can check more detail about animation on react native expo page
 https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/react-native/animated/#spring